# Xcode: Archiving a project to generate .ipa but export is not an option in Organizer

Tags: ios, high-sierra, xcode

I am a member of the Apple Developer program for my team and I have all the provisioning profiles in place and codesigning, but when I run **Product** -> **Archive** and get the Organizer pop-up, **Export** is not an available button for me.

I only have **Distribute App** and **Validate App** available as buttons. I am unclear what to do from here since all the documentation I have seen online says there was supposed to be an **Export** button available.

I am using Xcode 10.1 on High Sierra.

Comment: I *think* you need to archive first before you can export.  I believe you do Validate then Distribute then Export.

Comment: @fsb, you are providing some clues for me. I just noticed that I am archiving with my personal apple id instead of the apple id I have with the team. I changed it to my teams apple id, but now I get this error: This bundle does not support one or more of the devices supported by the previous app version. Your app update must continue to support all devices previously supported. You declare supported devices in Xcode with the Targeted Device Family build setting. Refer to QA1623 for additional information: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1623/_index.html

Comment: @fsb, I got it working. Please post your comment as an answer as it served as an excellent clue to point me where I needed to be.

Comment: I'd be very happy to add it as an answer (and get rep points!) but I'm not sure I actually supplied you the answer.  It looks like my comment helped but you were the one who figured it out.  My recommendation is that you answer, and accept, your own question.  Your answer might actually help someone else with a similar problem whereas my comment might now.  I'm glad you got it working!

Comment: @fsb, perhaps you can help me with another question. Once I selected how to distribute `.ipa`, I got `The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.`, but I think it should be a separate question.

Comment: I agree it should be a separate question.  Don't forget to use the search function to see if it's already been answered.  I know there's a lot of answers already provided on SO so be sure to look there, too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98639/discussion-between-daniel-and-fsb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So unless I am mistaken, with Xcode 10.1 on High Sierra at least, you will not find an Export button after running **Product** -> **Archive** in the process of generating an `.ipa`.

When you get the pop-up Organizer, instead, you want to click on the **Validate** button and just follow the prompts, once successful, then you can click on the **Distribute** button which will direct you to a pop up prompt asking you for method of distribution.